# How to set time of javascript date object

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have two widgets. A calendar and a Time Widget.

My calendar is a DateTime object  `Wed Apr 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400`  and my time outputs this result `1:00 AM`

I would like to Combine the two to make a new DateTime object. May I ask how about do I do that?

I tried this and it didn't work at all.

```
startDate.setTime(vm.startTime)
```

Comment: Do you use a moment.js or just vanilla?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine I use Moment.js

Comment: It will Help You!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you want this.
I hope I've been helpful

```
var startDate = { Date :"Wed Apr 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400" };
var startTime  = { Time :"1:00 AM" };


var DateTime  = Object.assign(startDate, startTime);

console.log(DateTime);
// { Date: 'Wed Apr 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400', Time: '1:00 AM' }
```

Edit:

```
var startDate = { Date :"Wed Apr 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400" };
var startTime  = { Time :"1:00 AM" };

var DateTime = { DateAndTime: startDate.Date + " " + startTime.Time};

console.log(DateTime);
//{ DateAndTime: 'Wed Apr 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 1:00 AM' }
```

Comment: not quite. that's an object with two properties. A datetime property and a time property. 

I am looking for a single object, DateTime object.

Comment: Did you mean an object with one property?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate your Object `entries` and get `values` to combine them through an array.

```
 mergeDateTime() {
    const DateTime = {
      a: "Wed Apr 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400",
      b: "1:00 AM",
    };

    const mergedDateTime = [];
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(DateTime)) {
      mergedDateTime.push(value);
    }
    return mergedDateTime;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with splitting you time string and setting `Hours` value of your date object.

```js
var startDate = "Wed Apr 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400";
var startTime = "1:00 AM";

var result = new Date(startDate);

var hour = parseInt(startTime.split(":")[0]);
var minute = parseInt(startTime.split(":")[1].split(" ")[0]);
var amPmOffset = startTime.split(" ")[1] == "AM" ? 0 : 12;

result.setHours(hour, minute + amPmOffset, 0);

console.log(result.toString());
```